# Getting url from active tab on external page

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have create a very simple addon for personal use. The only thing it does is show a "popup" with an external url. So far it works fine, but now I of course want to add features. For this I would like to access the url of the tab on which the extension is opened. I have tried many things, but I can't seem to put my finger on it. I would also be glad with the url being added as a parameter to the url of "default_popup".

This is my manifest.json:

```
{
  "browser_action": {
    "browser_style": true,
    "default_title": "Name of addon",
    "default_popup": "https://www.testdomain.com/dir/"
  },
  "icons": {
    "48": "lock.svg",
    "96": "lock.svg"
  },
  "description": "Open given page in window on top of browser I guess...?",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Name of addon",
  "version": "1.0.11",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],
  "applications": {
    "gecko": {
       "id": "name@testdomain.com"
     }
  }
}
```

It's probably just a simple thing for you seasoned developers, but I have only started today :)

Comment: @wOxxOm I don't need the contents, I'm only looking to getuse the URL of the tab on which the addon is activated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to declare the popup to use a page that belongs to the extension. The script inside that page will be able to get the current tab's URL and redirect the popup to the external site.

**manifest.json**, inside `browser_action` section:

```json
"default_popup": "popup.html"
```

Create **popup.html**:

```html
<script src="popup.js"></script>
```

Create **popup.js**:

```js
(async () => {
  const [tab] = await browser.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true});
  location.href = 'https://www.example.com/?foo=' + encodeURIComponent(tab.url);
})();
```